# Adding cell from one tableView to another

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, favorites

in relation to a other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811921/add-a-tableviewcell-to-a-new-tableview-by-tapping-a-button), I tried a few things to add a cell from one tableView to a new one. First of all I have a little picture which shows how this process should work.
[image]
There is the `CarsViewController` containing an array of cars. When you tap on one cell a new view (`CarDetailViewController`) which shows the details of each car and has got a `favoriteButton` opens. By tapping on this Button the cell of this car from the tableView (`CarsViewController`) should be added to a new tableView (`FAVViewController`) as you can see in the picture.

I've already tried something but it didn't work.
The `Car` class:

```
#import "Car.h"
@implementation Car
@synthesize name;
@synthesize speed;

@end
```

`CarsViewController`:

```
@implementation CarsViewController {
    NSArray *cars;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Car *car1 = [Car new];
    car1.name = @"A1";
    car1.speed = @"200 km/h";

  Car *car2 = [Car new];
    car2.name = @"A2";
    car2.speed = @"220 km/h";

cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:car1, car2, nil];
}
```

The `CarDetailViewController` with its button:

```
    @implementation CarDetailViewController{
        NSMutableArray *favoritesArray;
    }
...
    - (IBAction)setFAV:(id)sender {

        [favoritesArray addObject:car];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoritesArray forKey:@"favoriteCars"];

        }
```

And finally the `FAVViewController`:

```
@implementation FAVViewController{

    NSMutableArray *array;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoriteCars"]];


}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [array count];

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Car *cars2 = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *CarNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    CarNameLabel = cars2.name;

    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I`ve tried something to remove one cell from the tableView but after reloading the view all cells are away.

```
-(void)remove{
    [favoritesArray removeObject:car];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favoritesArray] forKey:@"favoriteCars"];
} //in CarDetailView
```

and...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)table commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        CarDetailViewController *instance = [[CarDetailViewController alloc] init];
        [instance remove];


        [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}
```

Comment: did you initialize favoritesArray...

Comment: I just have it in the implementation part

Comment: yes, you declared it, but did you `favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`..Nothing will be added to the array if you don't allocate space for it

Comment: I've put this into the viewDidLoad...but than there was a logText: `[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
__NSArrayM'.  
Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.`

Comment: you just need to add object to new array and reload table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `Car.m`

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [coder encodeObject:speed forKey:@"speed"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[Car alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        speed = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"speed"];
    }   
    return self;
}
```

In `setFav` method to store array

```
NSData *dataForArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoriteCars"];
if (dataForArray != nil)
{
    favoritesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataForArray]];

}

[favoritesArray addObject:Car];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favoritesArray] forKey:@"favoritesCars"];
```

And to retrieve array in favorites view controller

```
NSData *dataForArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"favoriteCars"];
if (dataForArray != nil)
{
    array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataForArray]];

}
```

This makes your custom objects conform to NSCoding so you can use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Thx...but now there's an error now in your last code line: No known class method for selector initWithArray

Comment: @user2242550 just fixed it

Comment: Yeah...now it works...but not everytime...it's not possible to have more than one favorite-cell...is it possible to save them?

Comment: Now it's only possible to have one favorite_cell at one time

Comment: Good...it works now, but not every cell/car is displayed in the favorite TableView...it's a bit like random whether it's displayed. And when it works the cell is displayed not right after the click but when you restart the app...it would be great if you also could help me with this problem

Comment: move the line where you retrieve the array in FAVViewController from `viewDidLoad` to  `-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` so that it gets the array everytime that view controller appears instead of just when its loaded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34169/discussion-between-user2242550-and-codeinorange)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the car to the CarDetailViewController's favoritesArray, you must add it to the FAVViewController's array.  Then you call reloadData on it's tableView.

You'll need to move the array property to the interface rather than the implementation, or better create a method that can do both of these for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedManager file in order to complete your requirement.
[MyManager.h](https://gist.github.com/ipreencekmr/6080931)
[MyManager.m](https://gist.github.com/ipreencekmr/6080942)

Create an instance of shared Manager in viewdidload as

```
_sharemanager=[MyManager sharedManager];
```

While going to detailViewController set selected Object to sharedManager object as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        DetailViewController *detailVC=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        [_sharemanager setCarDictionary:[carsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

On DetailViewController's viewDidLoad method create sharedManager instance and get selected Object Values and set to labels if any defined as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _shareManager=[MyManager sharedManager];

    carName.text=[[_shareManager carDictionary] valueForKey:@"name"];
    speed.text=[[_shareManager carDictionary] valueForKey:@"speed"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

And on click of favorite button set current object of sharedInstance to favorite array defined in sharedManager file as

```
-(IBAction)setMyFavorite:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *favArray=[_shareManager favCarsArray];

    if ([favArray indexOfObject:[_shareManager carDictionary]] == NSNotFound) {
        [favArray addObject:[_shareManager carDictionary]];
        [_shareManager setFavCarsArray:favArray];
    }
}
```

Similarly, At last on FavoriteViewController make sharedManager Instance and get favorite array list and reload favorite table as:-

```
favoriteCarList=[_sharemanager favCarsArray];
[favTable reloadData];
```

[DOWNLOAD SAMPLE HERE](http://ge.tt/8vejdpm/v/0)